# How to get VM details automatically by defining the resource group variables

Tags: azure, powershell

I am preparing PowerShell script to disable auto-shutdown option for all azure VMs in multiple resource groups. As of now I have prepare the script to disable auto shutdown option for a single resource group and single VM by defining the resource group name and VM name as variables. But I need to define only the resource group names as variable and I need to get the VM details from that resource group variable. Can some one please help me with this issue.

Below is the PowerShell script:

```
# Sign in to your Azure account
Connect-AzAccount

    # Define an array of resource group names
    $resourcegroups = @("RG-Test1",  "RG-Test2")
    
    # Define an array of VM names
    $vms = @("devvm1", "DevVm2")
    
    $shutdown_time = "0000"
    $shutdown_timezone = "India Standard Time"
    
    # Loop through resource groups and VMs
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $resourcegroups.Length; $i++) {
        $resourcegroup = $resourcegroups[$i]
        $vm = $vms[$i]
    
        $properties = @{
            "status" = "Disabled"
            "taskType" = "ComputeVmShutdownTask"
            "dailyRecurrence" = @{"time" = $shutdown_time }
            "timeZoneId" = $shutdown_timezone
            "notificationSettings" = @{
                "status" = "Disabled"
                "timeInMinutes" = 00
            }
            "targetResourceId" = (Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup -Name $vm).Id
        }
    
        New-AzResource -ResourceId ("/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/{1}/providers/microsoft.devtestlab/schedules/shutdown-computevm-{2}" -f (Get-AzContext).Subscription.Id, $resourcegroup, $vm) -Location (Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup -Name $vm).Location -Properties $properties -Force
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of below script to define only the resource group names as variable and get the VM details from that resource groups.

```c
# Define an array of resource group names
$resourcegroups = @("RG1", "RG2")

$shutdown_time = "0000"
$shutdown_timezone = "India Standard Time"

# Loop through resource groups
foreach ($resourcegroup in $resourcegroups) {
    $vmsInResourceGroup = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup
    
    foreach ($vm in $vmsInResourceGroup) {
        $properties = @{
            "status" = "Disabled"
            "taskType" = "ComputeVmShutdownTask"
            "dailyRecurrence" = @{"time" = $shutdown_time }
            "timeZoneId" = $shutdown_timezone
            "notificationSettings" = @{
                "status" = "Disabled"
                "timeInMinutes" = 00
            }
            "targetResourceId" = $vm.Id
        }
        
        $scheduleName = "shutdown-computevm-" + $vm.Name

        New-AzResource -ResourceId ("/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/{1}/providers/microsoft.devtestlab/schedules/$scheduleName" -f (Get-AzContext).Subscription.Id, $resourcegroup) -Location $vm.Location -Properties $properties -Force
    }
}
```

Now you can get the vm details and disable auto-shutdown option for all azure VMs in multiple resource groups. like below:

***Output***:

[image]